# Is there an alternative way to do "Paste and Match Style" in MacOS 10?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, osx-mavericks

The conventional keyboard shortcut for *Paste and Match Style* in MacOS 10 is <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.  This is somewhat tricky to type with two hands, and I find it very difficult indeed to type one-handedly.

- Can I change this shortcut to something else?  Or make another shortcut?  If so, how?
- Is there a mouse gesture that can be used instead?  If so, what is it?
- In extremis, are there alternative Mac keyboards that place <kbd>⌥</kbd>, <kbd>⇧</kbd>, and <kbd>⌘</kbd> more conveniently for this and similar shortcuts?

Comment: Everyone will do this differently. Try putting your thumb across ⌥⌘, pinky on the ⇧ and index finger on the V – or pinky on the ⇧, ring and middle finger on the ⌥⌘, and index finger on the V.